# Build Gimp from custom-path libraries

Tags: compiling, libraries, make, gimp

I'm installing Gimp (2.6.10) on Debian. The system has all the required libraries (dependencies) installed in the default directories, so giving to Gimp

```
./configure && make && make install
```

completes fine, and installs Gimp.

But I compiled some of the dependencies manually, for needed performance. These are GEGL, Glib, and BABL. All them are correctly installed in

```
--prefix /usr/handsoftware
```

I configure Gimp with these essential flags: (there are more flags to strip down unused features from the binary)

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/handsoftware/ PKG_CONFIG_PATH="../gegl/:../babl/" CXXFLAGS="-march=pentium4 -O3" CXXFLAGS="-march=pentium4 -O3"
```

where PKG_CONFIG_PATH points to the source directories of GEGL and BABL from which these libraries were compiled and installed. I don't know if this setting is correct nor required.

This `./configure`s correctly, but `make` fails pointing out that gegl.h is missing.

gegl.h is installed in two points in my system:

1. in the GNU `include` standard directory, where it's been installed by APT
2. in `../gegl/` , as pointed by PKG_CONFIG_PATH

I have to point Gimp to the manually-installed includes rather than to the ones installed by APT, as the formers are those compatible with the manually installed library. Can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable in front of `./configure` also I'm not sure if configure stores that value somewhere. My gut tells me not. `PKG_CONFGURE_PATH` is an environment variable and needs to be set, always. So you should `export` it prior to starting the build process. Also, PKG_CONFIG_PATH needs to point where the .pc files are. Are those the correct directories? I think it should rather be `/path/to/glib/install/dir/lib/pkgconfig`. You should always use absolute paths!

You are probaly still in trouble. You need something called a "staging" directory, where you install all your stuff. Gimp does not link libraries like glib statically. This means when you start your self-built gimp it needs to find libglib.so in your self-built version. This means the path to (for example) `libglib.so`  needs to be in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or mentioned in `/etc/ld.so.conf`. Is that the case in your current setup?